# Show that $(A \cup B)(C \cup D) = AC \cup AD \cup BC \cup BD$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Given nonempty subsets $A,B,C,$ and $D$ of $\mathbb{R}$, show that $(A \cup B)(C \cup D) = AC \cup AD \cup BC \cup BD$.

I am not sure how to go about proving this since we aren't given intervals. Also, it seems that we are using the product of sets here and not the cartesian product, and so breaking each set up into disjoint subintervals $(a,b)$ might help.

Comment: Is that $A\cdot B = \{xy: x\in A, y\in B\}$ or $A\cap B$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Pick a typical element on one side and show it belongs to the other side. Then do it the other way around. It's quite straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(A \cup B)(C \cup D) & = (A(C \cup D)) \cup (B(C \cup D))\\
& = (AC \cup AD) \cup (BC \cup BD)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where the both equalities is by distributivity, i.e.
$$X (Y \cup Z) = XY \cup XZ,$$
which should be proved formally below.

For $a \in X (Y \cup Z)$, we can find $b \in X$ and $c \in Y \cup Z$ such that $a = bc$. Since $c \in Y \cup Z$, we have either $c \in Y$ or $c \in Z$. If $c \in Y$, we have $a = bc \in XY$. Otherwise we have $c \in Z$ and $a = bc \in XZ$. Hence $a \in XY \cup XZ$. Since $a \in X (Y \cup Z)$ is arbitrary, this proves $X (Y \cup Z) \subseteq XY \cup XZ$.

Can you try to give a proof for the other way, i.e. $XY \cup XZ \subseteq  X (Y \cup Z)$?